# Subversion (Subclipse) in Eclipse - History, why latest revision is not the current version?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I notice it quite a bit that when I look at the History of a file in Subversion in Eclipse, the latest revision is not always the one that I am using, even though I have done an SVN Update, and done a revert on the file. I have included a screenshot as an example. Any ideas why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a stale cache of the SVN info.  Try doing Team > Refresh/Cleanup.